# How to build docker image with my local go package?

Tags: docker, go, package

My main.go file's path:
*/gowork/src/dockerpkgmain/main.go*

my package file's path:
*/gowork/src/dockerpkg/mult/mult.go*

my docker files path:
*/gowork/src/dockerpkgmain/Dockerfile*

```
main.go:

package main

import (
    "dockerpkg/mult"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("From different pkg")
    mult.Multiple()
}
```

mult.go:

```
package mult

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
)

func Multiple() {

    first := flag.Int("f", 0, "placeholder")
    second := flag.Int("s", 0, "placeholder")
    flag.Parse()
    out := (*first) * (*second)
    fmt.Println(out)

}
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.9.1

COPY . /go/src/dockerpkg/mult 

WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY . .

ADD . /go/src/dockerpkg/mult
RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...

CMD ["app"]

ENTRYPOINT ["app", "-f=7", "-s=9"]
```

If I try

```
COPY . /go/src/dockerpkg/mult
```

I got this:

> main.go:4:2: import "dockerpkg/mult" is a program, not an importable
>   package

What must I put in my dockerfile to build my image without changing project structure?

Comment: Please add your full `Dockerfile` to the question

Comment: Added Dockerfile full text

Comment: don't you need to `RUN go build -o main .`, too?

Comment: I tried now, the same result (I builded docker img without it, and it worked - i mean with only main.go file)

Comment: Can you try `COPY . /go/src/dockerpkg/` instead of `COPY . /go/src/dockerpkg/mult `? Also, do the same changes in `ADD`.

Comment: Oh, I guess I can delete add... it;s from my attempts, just forgot. Anyway, with or without ADD I got this: main.go:4:2: cannot find package "dockerpkg/mult" in any of:
 /usr/local/go/src/dockerpkg/mult (from $GOROOT)
 /go/src/dockerpkg/mult (from $GOPATH)

Comment: My bad. I didn't saw the file paths clearly. Never mind. Anyway, I will give it a try. BTW, what is your dockerfile's path?

Comment: Thank you, I'll be trying myself and waiting if you'll manage it. Dockerfile is in /gowork/src/dockerpkgmain/Dockerfile (in the folder with main.go)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your folder layouts, I guess your local $GOPATH is `/gowork` folder. In golang docker image, its $GOPATH is `/go` folder.

You have to create the docker file in this location `/gowork/src/Dockerfile`, then put the following in it. It works fine in my environment with your code.

```
FROM golang:1.9.1

COPY ./dockerpkg /go/src/dockerpkg

WORKDIR /go/src/app
COPY ./dockerpkgmain .

RUN go get -d -v ./...
RUN go install -v ./...

CMD ["app"]
```

Comment: @Mitch If you wanna know where you went wrong, you copied `main.go` file to both  `/go/src/dockerpkg/mult` and `/go/src/app`. So, when you are trying to get `package mult` , the program sees another `main` package in that directory. So it throughs error `import "dockerpkg/mult" is a program, not an importable package`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for explaining, I saw an issue where guy said that he has this mistake because his package was named main so I checked my mult (even few times)... So, this error (one of many I had in my ettemps) was really because of trying to use main, but without knowing... Thanks!

Comment: @Mitch, glad it works for you. Would you mind to access it as the answer? Thx.